# How much data is used to retrieve and store 1 timestamp in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm considering which price plan I should use for Firebase. How much data is used to retrieve and store 1 timestamp? I was considering using $25 a month plan, but the pay as you go might be a better option if it's as low of data as I think it is.

Comment: Just to store timestamps?

Comment: It was for thousands every week.

Comment: I could be wrong. Storing does not consume the bandwidth but downloading does. It's going to be very small for **ONLY** timestamp.